# Бесконечный таймер

Tags: c#, таймер

Как сделать бесконечный таймер, который раз в 15 секунд запускает определенную функцию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Он, в отличие от предложенного выше решения, не ест просто так потоки.

Comment: Как понять не ест потоки? Вообще-то этот самый Timer создает целых 2 потока, поток ожидания очереди событий, и поток отработки обратных вызовов привязанных к этим самым событиям. Если нам необходимо породить более 2 событий по таймеру - то да, Ваш способ намного лучше и производительней получится. А в случае всего 1 события?

Comment: В приведенном вами коде создается поток, вся суть которого состоит в ожидании, т.е. поток не делает ничего полезного. Он заблокирован ожиданием. Между тем, для любой системы справедливо утверждение: чем меньше потоков создано, тем лучше (потоки занимают память, создание/удаление потоков занимает время и, наконец, чем больше потоков, тем больше переключений контекста делается). Отсюда следует, что в идеале каждый поток в каждый момент времени должен выполнять какую-то работу.

Comment: Предложенное вами решение не согласуется с этим. System.Threading.Timer, в свою очередь, для ожидания использует системный таймер, и пока не истекает наш интервал, никакой поток не заблокирован. Затем, когда интервал истекает, берется свободный поток из пула потоков, и в нем выполняется установленный колбэк. После чего поток возвращается в пул, где может быть занят другой полезной работой.

Comment: Спасибо за рязъяснение.

Answer (score -1):

Используя потоки Thread, внутри функции потока использовать бесконечный цикл while(true) или for(;;), а для отмеривания отрезков времени задержку в виде Sleep.

Comment: Блокировать потоки -- плохо.

Comment: А можно узнать, каким образом производится ожидание срабатывания событий в классе Timer?

Comment: Через нативный таймер, предоставляемый CLR, который при срабатывании уведомляет управляемый код. Как это реализовано внутри ОС я не знаю, к сожалению. Какая-то системщина с прерываниями.